# Swift : Create a multi-function multicast delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wanting to use a multicast delegate to inform multiple objects when things change. The tutorials I've read that explain this, have a protocol that only has one function that is called directly on the array of delegates. That works fine when there is only one function defined. My Protocol has 6 functions. I want to avoid creating 6 separate functions and reuse a single function that can be applied to my array of delegates.

Quick example: (I understand this is none working, but I just want to get my idea across.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
 func method1()
 func method2()
 func method3()
}


class TestClass {
  var delegates = [MyProtocol]()

  func invokeDelegates(delegateMethod: () -> ()) {
    for delegate in delegates {
      delegate.delegateMethod()
    }
  }
}
```

The obvious problem is the compiler complains that "delegateMethod" isn't defined in the original protocol. Is there a way that I cast the method as being part of MyProtocol and the compiler will trust me?

Is this even possible?

Comment: No, because there's no specification as to which of the three methods you want to call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the signature of `invokeDelegates` to take a closure of type `(MyProtocol) -> ()`, and then you need to pass each delegate to the closure.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func method1()
    func method2()
    func method3()
}

class TestClass {
    var delegates = [MyProtocol]()

    func invokeDelegates(delegateMethod: (MyProtocol) -> ()) {
        for delegate in delegates {
            delegateMethod(delegate)
        }
    }
}
```

The closure should just invoke the appropriate delegate method on its argument. Swift can infer the argument and return types of the closure, and you can use the shorthand `$0` to refer to the argument, so the closure can be quite short:

```
let tester = TestClass()
tester.invokeDelegates(delegateMethod: { $0.method1() })
```

On the other hand, you could just use `Collection.forEach` directly on the `delegates` array (if it's accessible) and skip the `invokeDelegates` method:

```
tester.delegates.forEach { $0.method1() }
```

Answer (score 35):

Here is a gist of an Multicast Delegate pattern that I use in my projects. It also prevents from having strong reference cycles (memory leaks).  WeakWrapper handles this.

Ok. In some of the solutions I see mistakes (strong retain cycles, race conditions, ...)

Here is what I combine based on 1 day research. For the stack of delegates I used NSHashTable, so all the delegates are having weak reference.

```
class MulticastDelegate <T> {
  private let delegates: NSHashTable<AnyObject> = NSHashTable.weakObjects()

  func add(delegate: T) {
    delegates.add(delegate as AnyObject)
  }

  func remove(delegate: T) {
    for oneDelegate in delegates.allObjects.reversed() {
      if oneDelegate === delegate as AnyObject {
        delegates.remove(oneDelegate)
      }
    }
  }

  func invoke(invocation: (T) -> ()) {
    for delegate in delegates.allObjects.reversed() {
      invocation(delegate as! T)
    }
  }
}

func += <T: AnyObject> (left: MulticastDelegate<T>, right: T) {
  left.add(delegate: right)
}

func -= <T: AnyObject> (left: MulticastDelegate<T>, right: T) {
  left.remove(delegate: right)
}
```

**How to set delegate:**

```
object.delegates.add(delegate: self)
```

**How to execute function on the delegates:**
instead of

```
delegate?.delegateFunction
```

you use

```
delegates.invoke(invocation: { $0.delegateFunction })
```

Comment: You should explain why the loop is in reverse, also a little exemple for the delegates variable on the class that invokes the method would go a long way ;)

Comment: The idea for the reverse came from somebody else. I don't know what's going under-hood, but the reason it's added is because the objects inside the array are weak references and without the reverse function the code could end up with a runtime error when the objects get deleted from this table.

Comment: We need to `reverse` if remove multiple elements in the loop prevent from index mismatch and fatal error. In this case, just `break` the loop if removed.

Comment: [A ReversedCollection instance wraps an underlying collection and provides access to its elements in reverse order](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed) at the very moment it is called. That prevents situation in which: while iterating through delegates array some other entity would add/remove from that same array, which would result in a crash. Creating a copy and iterating on that copy prevents it.

Comment: In the `remove` method, why don't we directly use `delegates.remove(oneDelegate)` and use `===`? It would be helpful to know the reason behind this